# Information on unit test with error message

Tags: java, rest, junit

I'm new to doing unit tests but I've been attempting to achieve good code coverage and hit a line in my code, this one is regarding the error message. I've wrote a version which does seem to hit the particular line, but I wanted to make sure it's the correct method of doing so:

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException expectedEx = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void getName()throws Exception{
  Mockito.when(repository.findByName(test.getName())).thenReturn(null);
  expectedEx.expectMessage("Error message states it doesn't exist");

  service.getCByName(test.getName());
}
```

Is that the correct way of doing this or is there a better way to achieve this? The error is regarding a REST call where the name that is being passed in null, and therefore passing the error message.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Firstly, your intention is not very clear. Are you asking if this is the correct way to test for a thrown exception? If so, notice you forgot a call to `expectedEx.expect(ExceptionClass)`. Without this line *before* the code which is expected to throw the exception, the test rule will not be able to catch it properly

Comment: may be instead of mocking repository you can use embedded H2 database where you don't need mocking

Comment: Hey there, so I'm just trying to throw an exception so when this fails (which I know it should). It won't break but still pass since it passed out the message it should.

Comment: you should show your code to make things really clear. As a side note, you should favor JUnit 5 to JUnit 4 tests for new tests even if you have a JUnit 4 tests base because JUnit 5 allows to mix both JUnit 4 and JUnit5 Test.